# How to initialize a custom view(controller) so it works both programmatically and in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Suppose you implement a custom table view and a custom view controller (which mostly mimics `UITableViewController`s behaviour, but when initialized programmatically, ...

```
@interface Foo : MyCustomTableViewController ...

Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

... `foo.view` is kind of class `MyCustomTableView` instead of `UITableView`:

```
// MyCustomTableView.h

@protocol MyTableViewDelegate <NSObject, UITableViewDelegate>

// ...

@end

@protocol MyTableViewDataSource <NSObject, UITableViewDataSource>

// ...

@end

@interface MyCustomTableView : UITableView

// ...

@end

// MyCustomTableViewController.h

@interface MyCustomTableViewController : UIViewController

// ...

@end
```

How should you implement/override `init` methods in correct order/ways so that you could create and use an instance of `MyCustomTableView` both by subclassing `MyCustomTableViewController` programmatically or from any custom nib file by setting custom class type to `MyCustomTableView` in Interface Builder?

It important to note that this is exactly how `UITableView` (mostly UIKit for that matter) works right now: a developer could create and use either programmatically or by creating from nib, whether be it `File owner`'s main `view` or some subview in a more complex hierarchy, just assign data source or delegate and you're good to go...

So far I managed to get this working if you subclass `MyCustomTableViewController`, where I will create an instance of `MyCustomTableView` and assign it to `self.view` in `loadView` method; but couldn't figure out how `initWithNibName:bundle:`, `initWithCoder:`, `awakeFromNib`, `awakeAfterUsingCoder:`, or whatever else operates. I am lost in life cycle chain and end up with a black view/screen each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I solved my own issue:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    if (self.nibName) {
        // although docs states "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.", I am doing it instead of loading from nib manually, because I am too lazy ;-)
        [super loadView];
    }
    else {
        self.view = // ... whatever UIView you'd like to create
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a real mystery how the UITableViewController loads its table regardless of if one is hooked up in interface builder, however I have came up with a pretty good way to simulate that behavior.

I wanted to achieve this with a reusable view controller that contains a MKMapView, and I figured out a trick to make it happen by checking the background color of the view.

The reason this was hard is because any call to self.view caused the storyboard one to load or load a default UIView if didnt exist. There was no way to figure out if inbetween those 2 steps if the user really didn't set a view. So the trick is the one that comes from a storyboard has a color, the default one is nil color.

So now I have a mapViewController that can be used in code or in storyboard and doesn't even care if a map was set or not. Pretty cool.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //magic to work without a view set in the storboard or in code.
    //check if a view has been set in the storyboard, like what UITableViewController does.
    //check if don't have a map view
    if(![self.view isKindOfClass:[MKMapView class]]){
        //check if the default view was loaded. Default view always has no background color.
        if([self.view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && !self.view.backgroundColor){
            //switch it for a map view
            self.view = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            self.mapView.delegate = self;
        }else{
            [NSException raise:@"MapViewController didn't find a map view" format:@"Found a %@", self.view.class];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The strategy I've used when writing such classes has been to postpone my custom initialization code as late as possible. If I can wait for `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` to do any setup, and not write any custom code in `init`, `initWithNibName:bundle:` or similar methods I'll know that my object is initialized just like the parent class no mater what way it was instantiated. Frequently I manage to write my classes without any overrides of these `init` methods.

If I find that I need to put my initialization code in the `init` methods my strategy is to write just one version of my initialization code, put that in a separate method, and then override all the init methods. The overridden methods call the superclass version of themselves, check for success, then call my internal initialization method.

If these strategies fail, such that it really makes a difference what way an object of this class is instantiated, I'll write custom methods for each of the various `init` methods.